# Distributed dll and c++ objects - how some libraries handle this?

Tags: c++, qt, dll

Recently I found that passing/exposing objects to/from dll is dangerous if executable and dll was compiled with different compilers or even with different version of the **same** compiler or even with different settings of the **same** compiler! To say I was surprised is to say nothing - all this time I thought I can create a dynamic library and safely distribute it.

Now having this knowledge I wonder how certain libraries work? Let's take a dll in system32 folder. With dependency Walker I can see that in, say, `d3d11.dll` functions exposed with `C` parameter - I guess this is `C` convention which gives us a guarantee it will work. Also I know that `d3d11` works with `COM` objects, so there's no risk of creating an object in dll and destroying it in exe.

But now let's take any `Qt` dll - the functions exported as `c++` and have all their names mangled. I remember when I installed the framework I specified my compiler - MSVC2013, but I didn't specified a version! I can use a dll compiled with `update1` compiler in `update5` compiler and I can't remember any strange behavior. How it works then? How they handled mangled function name resolve, parameters passing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual reason that a library under windows has to be compiled with the same compiler is that the C++ standard library is not ABI compatible between different version of MSVC++. If a library uses the C++ Standard library across the dll boundary this is ok as long as the C++ standard library is identical in the library and the compiler that uses the library.

Qt expose there own strings (QString) and vectors(QVector) etc, instead of std::string and std::vector, therefore Qt doesn't expose the C++ standard library through the dll boundary, hence the Qt dll works with all versions of Visual Studio.

Comment: Thank you. I read about ABI and many resources says that any C++ object is not ABI compatible. Also, if I understand correctly, the name of the function (the mangled name) can differ from compiler to compiler. How this is handled?

Comment: @nikitablack Yes I don't think namemangling is part of the C++ standard, therefore every compiler can use there own mangling. The include .lib will tell the compiler which symbols are present in the .dll

Comment: That's a good point. So in order to distribute a dynamic library one have to distribute a lib also.

Comment: @nikitablack That is correct. A dll doesn't need a .lib at runtime, but does need it when compling against it. Note however static libraries also end in .lib on windows this tends to confuse people and a include .lib is very different from a static library.

Comment: I don't believe this is correct. In the vast majority of cases, it's not a breaking ABI change that causes trouble. Microsoft are insanely conservative in this area. If this were indeed the cause, then *any* user-defined type would be affected (`std::vector` as much as `QVector`). The reason is much more mundane: It's the allocator, that loses vital context when traveling a DLL boundary. [Potential Errors Passing CRT Objects Across DLL Boundaries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/potential-errors-passing-crt-objects-across-dll-boundaries) has more details.

Comment: @IInspectable I'm certainly no expert, however, I think this link argues otherwise: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/porting/binary-compat-2015-2017?view=vs-2019 and agrees with me.

Comment: The link explains, that *"object files, static libraries, dynamic libraries, and executables"* are binary compatible between all versions of Visual Studio starting with 2015. The link also points out, that up until 2015, artifacts produced by Visual Studio weren't binary compatible between different versions. Passing any non-ABI types across a DLL boundary is thus not supported. This applies to all non-ABI types (like `std::vector` or `QVector`). If passing a `QVector` across a DLL boundary appears to work, yet passing a `std::vector` doesn't, then this is not due to binary incompatibility.